# Java's Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK_IN_MONTH max value is 6. Is this correct?

Tags: java, calendar

As the title states, creating a *java.util.GregorianCalendar* object, let's say calendar, and running

```
calendar.getMaximum(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK_IN_MONTH)
```

it returns 6! To the best of my knowledge, this should be 5, since 
`calendar.getMaximum(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)` 
equals 31 and 31 / 7 == 4 with a remainder, i.e. there are at most 5 weeks and thus a day can occur at most 5 times in a month.

Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#DAY_OF_WEEK_IN_MONTH) states:

> For example, if a month has 31 days, DAY_OF_WEEK_IN_MONTH -1 will overlap DAY_OF_WEEK_IN_MONTH 5 and the end of 4.

This admits, that the maximum value can be 5. In order to have a reason for value six, there would have to be a month with 36 days, which shouldn't happen even with date/time corrections. At least I haven't found anything like that checking information about Gregorian calendar.

So yes, the maximum value should be 5.

---

*Edit:* I've also checked the source of the reference implementation and there is no reason for value 6.

Comment: Do you mean that there is no indication that a value of 6 would indicate the week after the DAY_OF_WEEK_IN_MONTH 5? (following javadocs' sense of *DAY_OF_WEEK_IN_MONTH 0 indicates the week before DAY_OF_WEEK_IN_MONTH 1*, which, in my opinion, is not very well written anyway)

Comment: @user2435660 I mean there is no indication that this field would ever be assigned a value greater than 5. Also, if you call `add(DAY_OF_WEEK_IN_MONTH, amount)`, for example, it doesn't matter what is the maximum value - it just adds/subtracts `amount * 7` days.

Answer (score 1):

You're right, it makes no sense.  For `DAY_OF_WEEK_IN_MONTH` to be `6`, there would have to be a month with 6 Mondays in it (for example).

Answer (score 0):

The reason why its 6 not 5 is because in English calendar, start day for a week is Sunday. If, for example, A month's first day, let's say July 1st is Sunday, then July 2nd is already the next week. Since July has 31 days, you end up with 6 weeks.

Comment: I doesn't really matter which day is considered as the first day of the week. For a specific Date, *DAY_OF_WEEK_IN_MONTH* shows if this is the 1st, 2nd ,3rd, ctra occurrence of the corresponding weekday, within the current month. So the maximum number should be the maximum possible number of occurences of the *same* week day within a month. If you check on your OS's calendar you will verify that even if a month *can* span 6 weeks, you cannot find the *same* weekday participating in all these, 6, weeks